# how to make a variable remember the result

Tags: java, object, variables, switch-statement

My program is ,,strategy game" where can user make his own army and avatars.My problem is that when users have to buy soldiers for his army.I don't know how to make a variable remember the result and user can buy another soldiers.I'm from Czech republic so on the line is translate for help.

```
int zustatek = 0; //residue

int penize = 50;//money
ArrayList<Vojak> armada = new ArrayList<Vojak>();//army
do {
System.out.println("Jaké si vybereš?"); //What you choose
System.out.println("Pešák-1(10)"); //plebs
System.out.println("Lučištník-2 (15)"); //archer
System.out.println("Jezdectvo-3 (30)"); //cavalry
System.out.println("Težká jednotka-4 (50)"); //hevy soldier
int volbaVojaku = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());//choose soldiers
Vojak vyberArmady = null;//picking soldiers
switch(volbaVojaku) {
case 1:

      System.out.println("A kolik jich cheš?");//how many soldiers do you want?
        int pocet = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());//number of soldiers
for(int i =0; i < pocet ;i++) {
     Zbran mec = new Zbran(0,0,0,10,"meč");//weapon
    Vojak pesak = new Pesak(nazevJednotky,0,0,0,mec,vysledekBrneni);//soldier
    vyberArmady = pesak;
    armada.add(pesak);//army
    System.out.println(pesak);
 }

pocet *=10;
zustatek = penize - pocet;
System.out.println("Zůstalo ti: " + zustatek);//Result how many user have
break;
```

Comment: You need to check if the user has enough money before you enter the for loop and starts to create soldiers

Comment: Declare `pocet` before the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the remaining money calculation to this:

```
pocet *=10;
penize = penize - pocet;
System.out.println("Zůstalo ti: " + penize);//Result how many user have
```

The initial money value (penize) gets decreased and saved on each purchase, you don't actually have to save the remaining money.